# How can I remove these discontinuity lines in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I'm plotting this:

[image]

Only problem: the vertical discontinuity lines. I don't know how to remove them. I understand what is happening, I asked pgfplots to draw something for me, and it doesn't understand when not to, so it plots these vertical lines. I'd like to avoid having to define several pieces of each of the colored lines, for it'd be too much work, and additionally, get rid of the lines over the x-axis that represent the zero value. Anyone got any idea of how? Below, the code for the picture.

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [%
    axis lines = center,ylabel=$\R$, xlabel= $X$, xlabel near ticks,xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymax=4, xtick=\empty, xticklabels=\empty
    ]
            
    \addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=250, name path=f, thick, color=blue]         {exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)};
                    \draw[black]  (5.21,1.5) node {$f$};
                    \addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, name path=f, thick, color=red]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<1.5,1<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),1,0)};     
                    \addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, name path=f, thick, color=orange]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<2,1.5<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),1.5,0)}; 
                    \addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, name path=f, thick, color=green]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<2.5,2<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),2,0)};   
                    \addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, name path=f, thick, color=purple]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<.5,.25<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),.25,0)};   

\end{axis}
```

\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `jump mark left`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}%grrr
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\newcommand\R{R}%grrr
\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [%
    axis lines = center,ylabel=$\R$, xlabel= $X$, xlabel near ticks,xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymax=4, xtick=\empty, xticklabels=\empty
    ]
            
    \addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=250, name path=f, thick, color=blue]         {exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)};
                    \draw[black]  (5.21,1.5) node {$f$};
                    \addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, name path=f, thick, color=red,jump mark left]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<1.5,1<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),1,0)};     
                    \addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, name path=f, thick, color=orange,jump mark left]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<2,1.5<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),1.5,0)}; 
                    \addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, name path=f, thick, color=green,jump mark left]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<2.5,2<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),2,0)};   
                    \addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, name path=f, thick, color=purple,jump mark left]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<.5,.25<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),.25,0)};   

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ridiculously effective. Thank you very much.